# Creating a Linkedin App: Can't see my Company page in the list

Tags: linkedin-api

Im trying to create a Linkedin app so I can use it for social login in my app.

Could you help me with the following case:

1) I'm trying to create a Linkedin app (https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/new)

2) I'm trying to select our Company in the "Company" field 
(I am an admin of our company Linkedin page: https://www.linkedin.com/company/28127545/ which was created a long time ago)

3) I can't see our Company on the list (but I can see other companies)

How can I create an app and select our Company? Does the company need to be verified somehow?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753509/2270041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for `More ApS` (Seems the second result is your company page):

[image]

Seems some problem with the `&` character (Probably a bug):

[image]

hope this help

Comment: Hi @IvanSiniak if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special botton when you write your personal information that says add a link (from the Company LinkedIn Website o) add the link and the logo will show up ;)