# Can't find my page when creating Linkedin App?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to connect Linkedin with a third party but I got an issue when I try to create a Linkedin App (https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp)

In the field "Company" I'm not able to find one of my page. I got the message "oops something went wrong..".
I'm admin on this page. Tried with others pages, it's working fine.
It may be related to the "&" in this company's name.
Tried with different writing/url code, but it doesn't appear either.

Can a Linkedin Dev help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Isofil what's the name of the company page? Have you aready see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666032/2270041 ?

Comment: Try to discover the company page without typing the `&` character as described in the related answer

Comment: Thank you Matteo. But If I put only the second part (after the "&") the autocompletion give me only 5 results, without mine.

Comment: Should be easier to get help with the name: I'm looking for "Technology & Strategy" based in France/Strasbourg (Schiltigheim)

Comment: Have you tried with the absolute url of the page? Other solutions could be using the HEX value in the URL Encoding standard: `%26` so try looking for `Technology %26 Strategy`

Comment: Thank you so much for this brillant idea! I had already tried with the absolute URL without succes, but not with the HEX "%26" which is working fine! thanks Matteo.

Comment: Cool!!! Can I post the comment as an answer so you can close your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time seems a bug exists in the UI of the "Create App" developer page for Company page with special chars in their name.

Seems as workaround is use the HEX value of the encoded chars as example, for the `&` char you can use `%26`  as example, in order to find a page named `Technology & Strategy`  you should use `Technology %26 Strategy` hope this help

Comment: Can't comment more on the previous 'feed', of course we can close my answer with yours. I think that I need to check it!  Thanks again :)